# How can we upload files to google colaboratory incrementally

Tags: google-colaboratory

I need to understand whether there is a way to incremental upload to Google Colaboratory.

I was trying to upload a huge number of image files to Google Colaboratory when my Internet connection failed and I had to start again. I observed that the images, which were already uploaded, where now getting duplicated.

Is there any way that only missed files get uploaded? This will save time and space.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you not to upload them just in Colab, because there is no solution to this problem, you just need to re-select manually the files not uploaded yet. I suggest you to use the google.colab package to manage these problems in Colab. Just upload everything you need to your google drive, then import:

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

In this way, you just need to login to your google account through google authentication API, and you can use files/folders as if they were uploaded on Colab. In this way, you can manage connection errors, since you're uploading them to google drive, and you can choose between overwriting existing files or just skip them.

Comment: Thank You

After a couple of days I found this to be the best way to handle it, with just a one time upload to Drive.